# Will the temperature of stop-bath and fixer during development affect the final result?

Tags: film, development

As we know the temperature of the developer is critical for 
film development. Usually it's 68F/20C.

Will the temperature of stop-bath and fixer also affect the final result of the image?

If so what is the suggested temperature?

Answer (score 5):

The rule of thumb is to keep all processing temperatures as close as possible to each other including the water rinses.

The problem that arises with temperature fluctuation is the stress it puts on the emulsion (a colloidal suspension of silver halide in gelatine). Uneven swelling and shrinking due to thermal changes can cause reticulation (failure) of the gelatine structure resulting in a distinctive crazing pattern. The affected areas are permanently affected.

[image: Reticulation pattern]

Comment: Something I've wondered but haven't tested is...what about gradual, one directional temperature changes? For example, 68F Dev, 72F Stop, 74F Fix, 80F Rinse? When living in Phoenix, I got lucky enough to live in older buildings with the pipes buried deep...but lots of new buildings that literally won't get cold tap during summer. It's conceivable that, living in that situation, one simply would have had to "make do."

Comment: @Hueco Those things happen. When one finds themselves in these kinds of circumstances, adding "hardener" (alum) to solutions will help. The downside to this chemical "toughening" is increased processing times. Chemicals don't migrate through the less swollen emulsion so well - both coming and going.

Answer (score 3):

All fluid baths should be close to the same temperature including water rinse, wash water, and washing aids. Film has multiple coats of material both front and back. Each layer, (there can be a dozen or more), has a different coefficient of expansion / contraction. If the temperature range is extreme, these various layers will slide. The least problem will be film curl, the worst, reticulation (cracking of the emulsion). One subtle result of just a few degrees variation is insipid reticulation, a slight worsening of the grain structure.